# Scale Set Agent Parallel Jobs Scaling Issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to execute jobs in parallel but I have the problem that scaling out takes 5 minutes per agent. Is this a bug or the expected behaviour (see the screenshoot below)?

I want to archive that the scaling out of the agents happens immediately, is this possible?

I added a small test example:

```
stages:
  - stage: BuildandTest
    displayName: Build And Test
    jobs:
      - ${{ each image in parameters.images }}:
        - job:
          displayName: Check images for vulnerabilities
          pool: "ap-oddb-dev-westeurope-001"
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: "Install Docker"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo ${{ image.name }}
                sleep 10m
                echo ${{ image.name }}
```

[image: Agent]

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug or the expected behaviour (see the screenshoot below)?

Yes, this is expected behaviour.

That is because Azure Pipelines samples the state of the agents in the pool and virtual machines in the scale set every **5 minutes**. The decision to scale in or out is based on the number of idle agents at that time.

You could check the document [How Azure Pipelines manages the scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#how-azure-pipelines-manages-the-scale-set) for some more details.

> I want to archive that the scaling out of the agents happens
> immediately, is this possible?

As mentioned in the first question, this is by default. So there is currently no way to archive that the scaling out of the agents happens immediately.

On the other hand, this design is also to save more resource consumption.

If our current VMSS use is completed, and then we have a new request, if the VMSS is closed immediately after the use is completed, it will consume more resources to delete and recreate a new iamge.

If we set a five-minute buffer time , within five minutes, if there is a new request, then VMSS does not need to delete the image and regenerate a new image, but only needs to reimage all the disks. This will save more resource overhead.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Are there any plans to add a feature in the future, to explicitly scale out the agents immediately?

Comment: @user2644964, AFAIK, There are no such plans yet. This involves not only a time delay issue, but also how to optimize resources, rather than frequent allocation and reclamation, which often causes more overhead than 5 minutes.